# The rendered text from the database always does not move to the next line,

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, laravel-5

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Hi, the rendered text from the database always does not move to the next line, it always stays in just one line whether i use `<h>` tags or `<p>` tags the same thing occurs, occasionally in all my apps. This what i mean, by the way i use foundation 5 and laravel.

[image: can you see the text rndering in one line]

ANOTHER EXAMPLE

[image: another example]

**This is my code**

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-9 columns">
    <h5 class="text-left grey-text montserrat-font uppercase">style description</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="text-con">
    <h6 class="grey-text montserrat-font testing">
    {{$style->style_description}}
    </h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because it does not contain any space. It is considered as a single word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your `testing` class have the required CSS. Add following rules to it.

```
.testing {
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add ellipsis instead of break-word.
`.testing{text-overflow: ellipsis;}`